# pycurl: how to reset a cookie session

Tags: python, pycurl

I'm using the following piece of code to get the content of a webpage from python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pycurl
import StringIO

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://google.com")
b = StringIO.StringIO()
c.setopt( c.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
#c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIESESSION, True);
c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookiefile.txt");
c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookiefile.txt");
c.perform()
page_data = b.getvalue()
```

For some reason

```
c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIESESSION, True);
```

gives an error. Does anybody know if this option is supported in pycurl?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry but this option is not supported in pycurl, but as I can see in the source code, it should be a fairly easy fix.
You should ask for it on the curl and python [mailing list](http://cool.haxx.se/mailman/listinfo/curl-and-python).

Answer (score 2):

This fixes the Problem:

```
import pycurl
pycurl.COOKIESESSION = 96
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess removing the cookiefile will have the same effect as setting COOKIESESSION to True.